# PHPDoc return type for MySQL Resource

Tags: phpdoc

What is convenient name return type for MySQL resource in PHPDoc?

example i have this code

```
/**
 * Get table data
 * @param type $table
 * @param type $select
 * @param type $condition
 * @return mysql_resource
 */
function getResource($table, $field, $condition) {
    $resource = mysql_query("SELECT $field FROM $table WHERE $condition ");
    return $resource;
}
```

as you can see `@return` i write `mysql_resource`,
is there any convenient name for return mysql resource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is typically handled by just "@return resource"... I believe just "resource" matches how var_dump() would show as the object's datatype.

Comment: thanks, i wonder if there is any other `resource` type than `MySQL` resource in PHP?

Comment: Yes... all database connections of any vendor are called "resource"... file handles are too.  It is generic, certainly.  You'd add more clarification in the tag's description piece:  "@return resource the query results from MySQL "